# Función para agregarBarcos C++

Tags: c++, function

Buenas gente la consigna es la siguiente:

```
void agregarBarcos( int tablero[N][N], int nuevos)
```

La función recibe como argumentos una matriz NxN de enteros (tablero) y un valor entero (nuevos). La matriz representa un tablero cuadricular de NxN casilleros. En cada casillero pueden agregarse uno o más barcos. Por lo tanto, el elemento correspondiente a la fila `x` y columna `y` de la matriz indica la cantidad de barcos posicionados en la coordenada horizontal `x` y la coordenada vertical `y`. El argumento entero (nuevos) indica la cantidad de nuevos barcos que se deben agregar al tablero.  La función debe solicitar que el usuario ingrese tantos pares de coordenadas como indicado por el argumento 'nuevos', y para cada coordenada valida agregar un barco en dicha posicion. De existir ya uno o mas barcos en la misma, se debe agregar un nuevo barco incrementando la cantidad preexistente. Si la coordenada ingresada fuera invalida, no debe agregarse barco alguno.

Pense la solución de la siguiente forma:

```
void agregarBarcos(int tablero[N][N],int nuevos)
{
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
            do{
            cin >> tablero[i][j];
            }
            while(i==nuevos);
            if(tablero[i][j]!=0){
                tablero[i][j]+=1;
            }
        }
    }


 }
```

No estoy entendiendo bien la consigna por lo tanto no estoy logrando que compile, tengo los siguientes errores:

```
_tester__.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
__tester__.cpp:33:1: error: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Werror=misleading-indentation]
 for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
 ^~~
__tester__.cpp:36:5: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘for’
     return 0;
     ^~~~~~
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda sea link de libro, video, cualquier cosa sirve.

Answer (score 2):

Los errores son claros y concisos, tal vez no los entiendas por estar en inglés, te los traduzco:

```
__tester__.cpp:33:1: error: this ‘for’ clause does not guard... [-Werror=misleading-indentation]
 for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
 ^~~
__tester__.cpp:36:5: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘for’
     return 0;
     ^~~~~~
```

```
__tester__.cpp:33:1: error: esta cláusula ‘for’ no corresponde con…  [-Werror=misleading-indentation]
 for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
 ^~~
__tester__.cpp:36:5: nota: … esta sentencia, la cuál está incorrectamente sangrada como si correspondiera con dicho ‘for’
     return 0;
     ^~~~~~
```

- `-Werror` es una opción del compilador que hace que las alarmas se comporten como errores.
- [Misleading](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/misleading) significa: hacer creer algo que no es cierto.
- [Indentation](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentaci%C3%B3n) se conoce en Español como [sangrado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sangr%C3%ADa_(tipograf%C3%ADa)) y es un tipo de notación secundaria utilizado para mejorar la legibilidad del código fuente.

En resumen, el error que tienes no es un error, es una alarma que te está indicando que el sangrado de tu código es confuso y sinceramente, tiene mucha razón.

---

> La función debe solicitar que el usuario ingrese tantos pares de coordenadas como indicado por el argumento 'nuevos', y para cada coordenada valida agregar un barco en dicha posición.

Tu código ni siquiera se acerca a hacer algo remotamente parecido, no tiene ningún sentido ni en el contexto del ejercicio ni en el contexto de algo coherente.

Mi propuesta es la siguiente:

```
for (int datos_leidos = 0; datos_leidos != nuevos; )
{
    unsigned x, y;
    std::cout << "Coordenada X: ";
    std:::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "Coordenada Y: ";
    std:::cin >> y;

    if (x >= N || y >= N)
    {
        std::cout << "Coordenadas incorrectas";
        continue;
    }
    else
        ++datos_leidos;

    ++tablero[x][y];
}
```

Las coordenadas son `unsigned` para que no acepten valores negativos; de esta manera basta con comprobar que las coordenadas no sean mayores que `N`, de serlo repetimos el bucle sin avanzar a la siguiente coordenada; en caso contrario sumamos un barco a la posición de las coordenadas. Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVLbbsIwDH1uvsJjElDBpMGgmrj0YXvneRNDU5aGKlJJUJIiEPTbmRNKobtpiS25x8eX2GXr9V3K2PF4KyTL8oTDRChjNaermBDLV@uMWgRzaUQqeQKzmGyUSICmmqdUP1HNlGkLaaHdtPQj41qF89kCpQsOlTnfKBOSPQE8S6XBkxNqlXnPuEiUgSncj@vIzbQMHEPoA0/h7lSdbLuwG1ewscloxFRuYTKBxrNSOuGSJhReRtD4ShMS4hi2/4h@/TUaa1e4WEJ7C/EUZnA4wM5bYeW99P5XKYPjYkprziw1VzXdYUpagQO5oEVl8czwGrnTuR7lVZedTrmg@XYx3y1OyQpSEOI2sqJCtt2eAvd1Zj4uUPYFZgnqGy8JXehFofPWntV6ky0H@nVj88YCza2C5lJkFEbn7CEJsNx3FqNGZJ7o@MgK6ulL/5gEP5UN8EGB5jbXEv8rUhyPvR5x4m8fdYgaeavv7xA1IoPSM0B7iBp59MF7HPIJ)</kbd>.

Comment: Podrías haberte ahorrado el `continue` añadiendo la última línea al `else`. Y nota que deberías usar `||` en vez de `&&`

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, pero habría perdido la oportunidad de mencionar el `continue` para despertar curiosidad sobre esa cláusula a lectores que no la conozcan.

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que entendí tienes que agregar tantos barcos según indica la variable `int nuevos`, siempre y cunado las coordenadas ingresadas sean validas. Seria algo como lo siguiente

```
void agregarBarcos(int tablero[N][N], int nuevos) {

  // iniciar tablero si es que aun no se ha hecho
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      tablero[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }

  // preguntar coordenadas para ingresar barcos
  for (int i = 0; i < nuevos; nuevos++) {
    int x, y;
    while (true) {
      std::cout << "ingrese coordenada x para el barco " << i << std::endl;
      std::cin >> x;
      std::cout << "Ingrese coordenada y para le barco " << i << std::endl;
      std::cin >> y;

      // valida coordenadas
      if (x < N && y < N) {
        tablero[x][y]++;

        // Si el valor es valido y se puede agregar en la matriz se sale del bloque while.
        break;
      } else {
        std::cout << "valores ingresados no son validos, intentar nuevamente." << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Y si el usuario introduce como coordenadas un número negativo? Además, no creo que inicializar la matriz dentro de la función `agregarBarcos` sea beneficioso, porque... ¿Cómo verificas que es necesario inicializarla?